# Start the timer when button is clicked in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you make it so that whenever you click the start button, only then will the timer starts. Because right now, it starts at will.

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.tick}> Start </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

What should I put in the onClick attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to bind 'tick' to the component in the constructor and move the code for starting the timer from 'componentDidMount' to 'tick' like so:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this); // bind to the component
  }

  tick() {
    // start timer after button is clicked
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.tick}> Start </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can achieve the same using React Hooks.

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = null;
    if(isActive){
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Seconds: {seconds}
      <br />
      <button onClick={()=>{
        setIsActive(true);
      }}> Start </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```